# How to add custom queues with back button

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am reviewing the documentation example of SweetAlert2, which generates a window with steps and includes the button to go back.

I can't find a way to configure the different queues as I want. According to the documentation, one can configure it with .queue (), but it is not working for me.

Does anyone know how to do it?

```js
const steps = ['1', '2', '3']
const swalQueueStep = Swal.mixin({
  confirmButtonText: 'Forward',
  cancelButtonText: 'Back',
  progressSteps: steps,
  input: 'text',
  inputAttributes: {
    required: true
  },
  reverseButtons: true,
  validationMessage: 'This field is required'
})

async function backAndForth () {
  const values = []
  let currentStep

  for (currentStep = 0; currentStep < steps.length;) {
    const result = await swalQueueStep.fire({
      title: 'Question ' + steps[currentStep],
      inputValue: values[currentStep],
      showCancelButton: currentStep > 0,
      currentProgressStep: currentStep
    })

    if (result.value) {
      values[currentStep] = result.value
      currentStep++
    } else if (result.dismiss === 'cancel') {
      currentStep--
    } else {
      break
    }
  }

  if (currentStep === steps.length) {
    Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(values))
  }
}

backAndForth()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const steps = ['1', '2', '3']
const swalQueueStep = Swal.mixin({
    confirmButtonText: 'Forward',
    cancelButtonText: 'Back',
    progressSteps: steps,
    input: 'text',
    inputAttributes: {
        required: true
    },
    reverseButtons: true,
    validationMessage: 'This field is required'
})
async function backAndForth() {
    const values = []
    let currentStep
    for (currentStep = 0; currentStep < steps.length;) {
        if (steps[currentStep] == 1) {
            var result = await swalQueueStep.fire({
                title: 'Question .' + steps[currentStep],
                inputValue: values[currentStep],
                showCancelButton: currentStep > 0,
                currentProgressStep: currentStep
            })
        } else if (steps[currentStep] == 2) {
            var result = await swalQueueStep.fire({
                title: 'Question ..' + steps[currentStep],
                inputValue: values[currentStep],
                showCancelButton: currentStep > 0,
                currentProgressStep: currentStep
            })
        } else if (steps[currentStep] == 3) {
            var result = await swalQueueStep.fire({
                title: 'Question ...' + steps[currentStep],
                inputValue: values[currentStep],
                showCancelButton: currentStep > 0,
                currentProgressStep: currentStep
            })
        } else {
            break
        }
        if (result.value) {
            values[currentStep] = result.value
            currentStep++
        } else if (result.dismiss === 'cancel') {
            currentStep--
        } else {
            break
        }

        if (currentStep === steps.length) {
            Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(values))
        }
    }
}
backAndForth();
```

Comment: I made a little changes to the script and got it to work, was looking for a solution too until I saw your post. watch out for "const result" it should be "var result"